# Wildcard in batch file not working as anticipated

Tags: windows, batch-file, wildcard, batch-processing, xcopy

I have a bunch of files named in a following pattern *FILENAME0.ext FILENAME1.ext FILENAME2.ext FILENAME3.ext FILENAME4.ext*, and I'm trying to copy files with specific numbers at the end of the filename to different folders.

So I do for example:

```
xcopy "C:\testfolder\*1.ext" "C:\testfolder\folder1"
```

But for some reason it doesn't only copy the files ending with 1, but also some of the other files (kinda inconsistently).
Strangely - it does work correctly for files with filenames ending with 0.
It seems that there is something I don't understand about the * wildcard? Or maybe there is a better way to do this task?

Comment: What does `dir /x "C:\testfolder\*1.ext"` show?

Comment: Well, thanks for that. dir with /x showed files with filenames ending with 1 but also in their short filename (8.3 filename). I didn't know files could have two filenames. I also found a solution - to filter the short filename out:

`for %%A in (C:\testfolder\*1.ext) do @echo %%A | >nul findstr 1.ext && xcopy "%%A" "C:\testfolder\folder1"`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `where.exe`, which ignores the 8.3 names:

```batch-file
@For /F Delims^= %%G In ('"(Set PATHEXT=) & "%__AppDir__%where.exe" "C:\testfolder":"*1.ext" 2> NUL"') Do @"%__AppDir__%xcopy.exe" "%%G" "C:\testfolder\folder1\" /QHRKY 1> NUL
```